# How to use Excel column chart for datasets that have very different scales

Tags: excel, charts, scaling

There are 2 datasets that have values in the interval [0; 1]. I need to visualize these 2 datasets in Excel as a column chart. The problem is that some data points have values 0.0001, 0.0002, and other data point have values 0.8, 0.9, etc. So, the difference is hugde, and therefore it´s impossible to see data points with small values. What could be the solution? Should I use logarithmic scale? I appreciate any example.

Comment: Why don't you graph the second set of data against the right axis on a different scale? Or even "normalise" the second data set by mulitplying it by 1000

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways below

1. Graph the smaller data set as a second series against a right hand Y axis (with same ratio from min to max as left hand series)
2. Multiply the smaller data set by 1000 and compare the multiplied data set to the larger one

Note that a log scale will give negative results given you are working with fractions, so that isn't really an option

[image: graphs]